# Using NetLogo's csv extension to read special characters

Tags: csv, unicode, netlogo, ansi

Working with data in Guinea there are administrative boundaries with special characters, specifically:

Guéckédou

The CSV was apparently created/edited in Mac and Notepad++ detects it as ANSI and displays correctly on my Windows machine. It's working fine in Excel too but in NetLogo, for example when printing in the Command Center, it's:

Gu�ck�dou

Creating a CSV in notepad++ where UTF-8 is enforced works with the csv extension.

Not sure if it's related but a somewhat similar problem seems to be when exporting the world to csv and opening in Excel- it gives the following for a perfectly fine string that was added as attribute to patches using the gis extension:

GuÃ©ckÃ©dou

Is there a way to consume that CSV other than converting it to UTF-8?

Comment: I believe you will have to convert it to UTF-8.